# G is a group. $a*b*a^{-1}=e$ prove that $ b=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $a,b \in G$ are such that $a*b*a^{-1}=e$. Prove that $b=e.$` 
I know that e is the identity element and $e=a*a^{-1}$ in general but I don't get how to prove that $b=e$ in this case.

Comment: Well, you multiply by $a$ on the right and by $a^{-1}$ on the left.

Comment: An overkilling solution is to show that $g\mapsto aga^{-1}$ is a group automorphism.  Since $e\mapsto e$ and $b\mapsto e$ under this automorphism, we must have $b=e$.

Comment: @freakish This is probably a dumb question but how can you multiply by $a$ on the right and not need to on the left? Maybe I just need to brush up on algebra skills..

Comment: What is meant is that the equation $a*b*a^{-1} = e$ implies $a*b*a^{-1}*a = e * a$.  Since we are not assuming the group is Abelian (all elements commute with each other), you need to specify if you are operating on the right or left side of the expression ($x*y$ maybe $\not=y*x$.  But, just like in regular arithmetic, when you have an equality, you can do the same thing to both sides of the equation to preserve equality, e.g. $x = 2$ implies $x +5 = 2 + 5$.

Comment: I still am not understanding how you get $b=e$ by multiplying $a$ on the right and $a^-1$ on the left.

Comment: I have removed many off-topic comments here. Please stay on topic. Also, as there are no actual answers, it would still be best if someone wrote a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so lets brake it down. Assume that $x, y, z\in G$. Obviously $x=y$ implies $x*z=y*z$. On the other hand if $x*z=y*z$ then $x*z*z^{-1}=y*z*z^{-1}$ so $x*e=y*e$ and finally $x=y$. All in all we have:

$$x=y \mbox{ if and only if }x*z=y*z$$

This is known as the multiplication on the right side by $z$. Analogous is the multiplication on the left side by $z$:

$$x=y \mbox{ if and only if }z*x=z*y$$

Now you can apply this to your equality:

$$a*b*a^{-1}=e\mbox{ if and only if }a*b*a^{-1}*a=e*a$$

So we used multiplication on the right by $a$ and we obtain $a*b=a$. Now apply multiplication on the left by $a^{-1}$:

$$a*b=a\mbox{ if and only if }a^{-1}*a*b=a^{-1}*a$$

and thus $b=e$.